# Can I use VPN only for internet access and not on my entire computer?

Tags: vpn

I signed up for VPN service, downloaded their VPN program and ran it.  It works perfectly except that when it's running my networked drives stop working and Outlook keeps asking me to re-enter my logging information.  So I'm wondering if there is a way I can use VPN only when I'm browsing the internet, or does only using it on internet defeat the entire purpose of VPN?

Comment: The purpose of being connected to a VPN is to literally connect to another network which you are not physically connected to otherwise.

Comment: @Ramhound correct, but it is perfectly reasonable to be connected to two separate networks simultaneously.  Alex, most VPN's allow you to select whether to route ALL of your traffic thru the vpn, or only that which is needed.  See if you can find a setting that has some sort of toggle like that

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that what you are asking for IS theoretically possible but not generally recommended as it is complex to achieve reliably.

The long answer:

As @Ramhound states, the main purpose of a VPN is to extend a remote LAN (Local Area Network) over an insecure WAN (Wide Area Network). This means that your local network (or when set up from Windows, just your PC) is an extension of the remote network and all traffic should be directed via the remote network.

What you are asking for is "Split Tunnelling". Not only does this potentially reduce the security of the VPN, it is also difficult to set up and maintain.